# "Exclusive" or "exclusively"?

Tags: word-choice

If I want to let a customer know that their company can only buy spare parts from us, and put this information into documents.  Which of my sentences below would be correct? Or are there other ways to express it still using the words *exclusive* or *exclusively*?

The sentences I have in my mind are:

> 1. All spare parts shall be exclusive from [our company name].
> 2. All spare parts shall be bought exclusively from [our company name].
> 3. All spare parts shall be provided exclusively by [our company name].
> 4. All spare parts shall be bought/provided exclusively by/from [our company name].

Comment: Your other question should rather be asked separately.

Comment: Got it.  I will post the other question once this question is answered.  Thanks.

Comment: I feel that the first sentence would not be used from native speakers.

Comment: I'd vote for #2.

Comment: I like #2 as well although I'd opt for *purchased* instead of *bought*

Comment: A great basic question. Why can't I see upvotes? :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is that “exclusive” on its own probably does not convey enough information to be understood clearly as an indication of an *exclusive provisorship*, so if you're set on this construction you’re probably better off using one of the “exclusively” options.

Let’s start with a look at each phrasing you’ve thought of, and then I’ll suggest an alternative.

> All spare parts shall be exclusive from [company name].

As I mentioned above, “be exclusive from” isn’t universally intelligible as establishing an exclusive vendor.

> All spare parts shall be bought exclusively from [company name].

This one works well, but I agree with [Jim](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/147/jim) that “purchased” sounds better here. All I can say is that it seems like a better match for the formal tone of the sentence. This option is the most exact and clear.

> All spare parts shall be provided exclusively by [company name].

This one is also quite clear, and has the advantage of de-emphasizing the cost by not mentioning these compulsory transactions as such. This also detracts from its exactness, however, because “provide” *could be* interpreted as “given for free”.

> All spare parts shall be bought/provided exclusively by/from [company name].

Simply too clunky. The main problem is probably that it involves two options without necessarily conveying which one of each pair goes with which one of the other.

---

If you don’t necessarily need to phrase it this way, you could use “exclusive” as an adjective describing your company (instead of using it to describe the parts). Then you’d write it something like this:

> [Company name] shall be the exclusive provider of spare parts.

Comment: Won't it be "will be" in `All spare parts shall be exclusive from [company name].`?

Comment: @Mistu4u: I assume this is for a business contract. I share the opinion of [this article](http://www.adamsdrafting.com/shall-will-must-exchange-emails/)'s author that "shall" has its place in such contexts "to impose an obligation on the subject of the sentence, as in _'Acme shall purchase the Shares.'"_